# how can I enable sshd on MacOS ventura, if "systemsetup -setremotelogin on" doesn't work?

Tags: firewall, macos

I am trying to enable remotelogin on MacOS (Ventura). "sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on" says it is already enabled (confirmed by the GUI), but if I try to login from my Linux PC I get

```
% ssh harri@10.42.100.13
ssh: connect to host 10.42.100.13 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Both system application firewall and packet filter have been disabled (temporarily). "Allow access for" has been set to "All users" in the preferences. Using tcpdump on the Macbook I see incoming traffic for destination port 22/tcp. The Mac doesn't answer.

There is no problem for "ssh localhost" or "ssh 10.42.100.13" on the Mac itself. The Mac can ping my Linux PC without problems.

Every helpful hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault: System Integrity Protection was still off. After turning it on again I can login via ssh.

Hope this is helpful for somebody out there running into the same pitfall.

Comment: FYI: You can select your own answer as the "accepted" answer. This won't get you any points, but does call more attention to the Q&A - thereby potentially helping more people.